# Scraping .aspx page with python

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup

I am new the web-scraping game. I am trying to scrap the following website: 
http://www.foodemissions.com/foodemissions/Calculator.aspx

Using resources found on the Internet, I put together the following HTTP POST request:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
}

class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17'

myopener = MyOpener()
url = 'http://www.foodemissions.com/foodemissions/Calculator.aspx'
# first HTTP request without form data
f = myopener.open(url)
soup_dummy = BeautifulSoup(f,"html5lib")
# parse and retrieve two vital form values
viewstate = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
viewstategen = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']

soup_dummy.find(id="ctl00_MainContent_category")

#search for the string 'input' to find the form data
formData = (
    ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
    ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR', viewstategen),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$transport', '200'),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$quantity','1'),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$wastepct','100')
)

encodedFields = urllib.urlencode(formData)
# second HTTP request with form data
f = myopener.open(url, encodedFields)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,"html5lib")
trans_emissions = soup.find("span", id="ctl00_MainContent_transEmissions")
print(trans_emissions.text)
```

The output from my final print command doesn't seem to change even when I change the `ctl00$MainContent$transport` element. Any pointers on why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about BeautifulSoup, but are you making a post or a get?

Comment: I am trying to make a POST

Comment: As an aside, make sure you encode your fields: `encodedFields = encodedFields.encode('ascii')`, otherwise it'll throw a type error when you try to POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the ASP.NET App "think" that you clicked the calculate button by adding the button name to the `__EVENTTARGET` hidden input.

```
formData = (
    ('__VIEWSTATE', viewstate),
    ('__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR', viewstategen),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$transport', '100'),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$quantity','150'),
    ('ctl00$MainContent$wastepct','200'),
    ('__EVENTTARGET', 'ctl00$MainContent$calculate')
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks @kblok.

Comment: Another quick question; how did you know `__EVENTTARGET` was associated with `ct100$MainContent$calculate`? I don't see any connection between them in the page source.

Comment: @varun because that’s part of the ASP.NET internals. In order to implement server control events, like a `calculate.click`, ASP.NET needs to know somehow which is the control performing a post. That’s being solved using the __EVENTTARGET and the __EVENTARGUMENTS (if needed) but the click has no arguments.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks for this answer. I am working on something similar now, however this code does not work, it says: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tex

Comment: @hardkoded could you take a look at this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165790/how-to-deal-with-eventvalidation-in-asp-net-web-scraping