# Scraping ASPX form and avoiding Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I asked previously (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927385/scrape-aspx-form-with-python)) how to scrape results from an ASPX form. The form renders the output in a new tab (by using the function `window.open` in JS). In my previous post, I wasn't making the correct POST request, and I solved that.

The following code successfully retrieves the HTML code from the form with the correct request headers, and it's exactly equal to the POST response I see in the Chrome inspector. But (...) I can't retrieve the data. Once the user make the selections, a new pop-up window opens, but I am not being able to catch it. The pop-up window has a new URL and its information is not part of the request response body.

Request URL: `https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/CommodityStatistics/Statistics.aspx`

Pop-up URL [the data I want to download]: `https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/CommodityStatistics/ViewReport.aspx`

```py
url = 'https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/CommodityStatistics/Statistics.aspx'

with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Referer": "https://apps.neb-one.gc.ca/CommodityStatistics/Statistics.aspx",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        }

        response = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

        data = { tag['name']: tag['value'] 
            for tag in soup.select('input[name^=ctl00]') if tag.get('value')
            }
        state = { tag['name']: tag['value'] 
                for tag in soup.select('input[name^=__]')
            }

        payload = data.copy()
        payload.update(state)

        payload.update({
            "ctl00$MainContent$rdoCommoditySystem": "ELEC",
            "ctl00$MainContent$lbReportName": '76',
            "ctl00$MainContent$rdoReportFormat": 'PDF',
            "ctl00$MainContent$ddlStartYear": "2008",
            "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$MainContent$rdoCommoditySystem$2"
        })

        print(payload['__EVENTTARGET'])
        print(payload['__VIEWSTATE'][-20:])

        response = s.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

        state = { tag['name']: tag['value'] 
                 for tag in soup.select('input[name^=__]')
             }

        payload.pop("ctl00$MainContent$ddlStartYear")
        payload.update(state)
        payload.update({
            "__EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$MainContent$lbReportName",
            "ctl00$MainContent$lbReportName": "171",
            "ctl00$MainContent$ddlFrom": "01/12/2018 12:00:00 AM"
        })

        print(payload['__EVENTTARGET'])
        print(payload['__VIEWSTATE'][-20:])

        response = s.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

        state = { tag['name']: tag['value']
                 for tag in soup.select('input[name^=__]')
                }

        payload.update(state)
        payload.update({
            "ctl00$MainContent$ddlFrom": "01/10/1990 12:00:00 AM",
            "ctl00$MainContent$rdoReportFormat": "HTML",
            "ctl00$MainContent$btnView": "View"
        })

        print(payload['__VIEWSTATE'])

        response = s.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
        print(response.text)
```

There is any way to retrieve the data from the pop-up window using `requests` and `bs4`? I noticed that `html-requests` can parse and render JS, but all my trials have been unsuccessful.

The url source shows this JS code, which I guess is the one opening the pop-up window with the data:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.open("ViewReport.aspx", "_blank");Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
```

But I'm unable to access to it.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted your solution to the last question you asked so others can learn from it.

Comment: Done! I added the cross-reference.

Comment: Pass clicks into XPATH objects? I don't think it's clear what you're trying to do or what your issue is.

Comment: @pguardiario, I rephrase some of my statements in the question to make myself clearer. The issue is basically that in the browser, once I click view a new pop-up window. I tried to make the correct requests, but I'm not able to retrieve the pop-up data using the code posted above. There's a non-selenium option that can help me?

Comment: I think you're getting confused by the popup window -> a request is just a request. If you make the same request that your browser makes you will get the same response. Look in the network tab of chrome dev tools to find the right form data.

Comment: @pguardiario, that was just what I made. If you run my code, you'll notice that the response I'm printing is exactly the same body of the response I get in the Chrome inspector (`Statistics.aspx` POST request) when I make click on "View". The response runs a JS function in the background that open a window with the data, but I'm unable to replicate that behavior in Python. That's my question.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting the right response so I don't see what your issue is.

Comment: I change the question to address exactly my problem. I'm getting the new response, but the data opens in a new URL which I can't acess through the Python request I am making.

Comment: were you able to get a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

See this scrapy blog https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition

I have used this concept in the past in order to scrape aspx pages.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the share, but `scrappy` will only make my POST request cleaner (I've done three request to simulate the UI behavior and deal with the different `__VIEWSTATE` values, that's why I update my `payload` at each request), but it will return the same HTML body eventually. My problem is that the data is open in a new tab, not in the body of the response.