# Scraping .aspx page with Python yields 404

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a web-scraping beginner and am trying to scrape this webpage: https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/ap.aspx

I'd like to be able to put in some settings at the top (like District, 2020-2021, Computer Science A, Female) and then download the resulting data for those settings.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/ap.aspx'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
    r = s.get('https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/ap.aspx')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    data = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    
    
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddReportType"]="DISTRICT",
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear"]="2021",
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddSubject"]="COMSCA",
    data["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddStudentGroup"]="F",
    
    p = s.post(url,data=data)
```

When I print out `p.text`, I get a page with title  `'\t404 - Page Not Found\r\n'` and message

```
<h2>We are unable to locate information at: <br /><br '
 '/>http://profiles.doe.mass.edu:80/statereport/ap.aspxp?ASP.NET_SessionId=bxfgao54wru50zl5tkmfml00</h2>\r\n'
```

Here's what `data` looks like before I modify it:

```
{'__EVENTVALIDATION': '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',
 '__VIEWSTATE': '/wEPDwUKLTM0NzY4OTQ4NmRkDwwPzTpuna+yxVhQxpRF4n2+zYKQtotwRPqzuCkRvyU=',
 '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '2B6F8D71',
 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnViewReport': 'View Report',
 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hfExport': 'ViewReport',
 'leftNavId': '11241',
 'quickSearchValue': '',
 'runQuickSearch': 'Y',
 'searchType': 'QUICK',
 'searchtext': ''}
```

Following suggestions from similar questions, I've tried playing around with the parameters, editing `data` in various ways (to emulate the POST request that I see in my browser when I navigate the site myself), and specifying an `ASP.NET_SessionId`, but to no avail.

How can I access the information from this website?

Comment: what are your params  `p = s.post(url,data=data,params=params)`

Comment: @Flow Removed, thanks for pointing that out! Currently I'm not using any, but I was experimenting with setting the ASP.NET_SessionId, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __VIEWSTATE, and __EVENTVALIDATION there.

Comment: What are you trying to get? If you would want to make it so you would access something maybe instead of web scarping try selenium.

Comment: @Flow If you go to the webpage, put in some settings, and click "View Report", it shows a data table; that's what I'd like to get (whether directly from the page's text or using the "Export" button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adapting the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927385/scrape-aspx-form-with-python). I'm not sure *why* editing the payload in this way made the difference, so I'd be grateful for any insights!

Here's my working code, using Pandas to parse out the tables:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/ap.aspx'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
    
    response = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

    data = { tag['name']: tag['value'] 
        for tag in soup.select('input[name^=ctl00]') if tag.get('value')
            }
    state = { tag['name']: tag['value'] 
        for tag in soup.select('input[name^=__]')
            }
    
    payload = data.copy()
    payload.update(state)
    
    payload["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddReportType"]="DISTRICT",
    payload["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddYear"]="2021",
    payload["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddSubject"]="COMSCA",
    payload["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddStudentGroup"]="F",
    
    p = s.post(url,data=payload)
    df = pd.read_html(p.text)[0]
    
    df["District Code"] = df["District Code"].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
    display(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for what I did was use bs4 to parse HTML data and then found the table. Then I get the rows and to make it easier to work with the data I put it into a dictionary.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://profiles.doe.mass.edu/statereport/ap.aspx'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find_all('table')
    rows = table[0].find_all('tr')
    data = {}
    for row in rows:
        if row.find_all('th'):
            keys = row.find_all('th')
            for key in keys:
                data[key.text] = []
        else:
            values = row.find_all('td')
            for value in values:
                data[keys[values.index(value)].text].append(value.text)

for key in data:
    print(key, data[key][:10])
    print('\n')
```

The output:

```
District Name ['Abington', 'Academy Of the Pacific Rim Charter Public (District)', 'Acton-Boxborough', 'Advanced Math and Science Academy Charter (District)', 'Agawam', 'Amesbury', 'Amherst-Pelham', 'Andover', 'Arlington', 'Ashburnham-Westminster']


District Code ['00010000', '04120000', '06000000', '04300000', '00050000', '00070000', '06050000', '00090000', '00100000', '06100000']


Tests Taken ['     100', '     109', '   1,070', '     504', '     209', '     126', '     178', '     986', '     893', '      97']


Score=1 ['      16', '      81', '      12', '      29', '      27', '      18', '       5', '      70', '      72', '       4']


Score=2 ['      31', '      20', '      55', '      74', '      65', '      34', '      22', '     182', '     149', '      23']


Score=3 ['      37', '       4', '     158', '     142', '      55', '      46', '      37', '     272', '     242', '      32']


Score=4 ['      15', '       3', '     344', '     127', '      39', '      19', '      65', '     289', '     270', '      22']


Score=5 ['       1', '       1', '     501', '     132', '      23', '       9', '      49', '     173', '     160', '      16']


% Score 1-2 ['  47.0', '  92.7', '   6.3', '  20.4', '  44.0', '  41.3', '  15.2', '  25.6', '  24.7', '  27.8']


% Score 3-5 ['  53.0', '   7.3', '  93.7', '  79.6', '  56.0', '  58.7', '  84.8', '  74.4', '  75.3', '  72.2']



Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like this lets me process the default data on the front page, but I'd like to be able to specify settings (like District, 2021, Computer Science A, Female in my example above) and then download the data - specifying the settings is what I'm getting stuck on. I'll clarify the question.